# Calculating A Percentage Of System Ram With Batch Script (Using In Dynamic Memory Management Modification)

Tags: windows, batch-file, percentage, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I think I have this correct but for some reason it's not reading from the output file "ram.dat". Can anyone find the error in this?

```
@echo off
set percent=90

:ramcalc
cls
if %percent% GTR 90 Echo Needs To Be Less Than 90
if %percent% LSS 1 Echo Needs To Be Greater Than 1
echo Type Percent Of Ram To Calculate
set /p percent=1-90:
if %percent% GTR 90 goto ramcalc
if %percent% LSS 1 goto ramcalc

cls Calculating...
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set vidx=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (ram.dat) do (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    set var!vidx!=%%A
    echo %%A
)
set var > test.txt
calc %var2%+%var3%+%var4%+%var5% >tmp
set /p add= < tmp
del tmp
calc %add%/1000000 >tmp
set /p divide= < tmp
del tmp
calc %divide%*0.%percent% >tmp
set /p ram= < tmp
del tmp
set /a round=%ram%+0
set ram=%round%
calc %ram%/1024 >tmp
set /p gb= < tmp
del tmp
set /a ramb=%gb%+0

cls
echo %percent% Rounded Is %ram%MB Approxamatly %ramb%GB 
pause
goto ramcalc
```

I'm going to be using this in a dynamic memory modification and it is just a modified sample of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was typing the answer to your other question when it suddenly vanished.  In that question you were dealing with three complexities.  1) Math operations in DOS are limited to 32-bit numbers.  2) WMIC outputs Unicode, so it throws off the `for /F` command.  3) `endlocal` discards the `ram` variable.  Here's what I came up to solve all three problems:

```
@echo off

wmic memorychip get capacity>ram.dat
type ram.dat>ram.txt
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set /p percent=Enter percentage (1-100): 

set vidx=0
set var1=0
set var2=0
set var3=0

for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%i in (ram.txt) do (
  if "!tmp!" NEQ "" (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    set var!vidx!=%%i
  )
)

set /a var1/=1048576
set /a var2/=1048576
set /a var3/=1048576
set /a total=!var1!+!var2!+!var3!
set ram=!total!MB

del ram.dat
del ram.txt

endlocal &set /a ram=%total% * %percent% / 100

set ram=%ram%MB
set ram
```

This will calculate the ram for 3 memory card slots, leaving the `ram` environment variable set at the end of running the batch file.  Your new code in your current question looks like you want to calculate a percentage of the available ram.  I don't think you can do decimal math in DOS, so you're going to have to use another formula.

### Edit 1

I updated the example to include the percentage you included in your second question.  You still need to add the bounds checking.

Comment: oh i have it now for the calculation but its not reading the file, btw here is my new script. im about to update this so you can see, i used an external calculation program for it but it gives the plain output aswell.